# Run a Chrome Extension with content scripts from a puppeteer server

Tags: google-chrome-extension, puppeteer

I have developed a Chrome extension that scrapes some pages that are visited.
Now I would like to run this extension on a remote server using
Puppeteer and simulate the opening of web pages.
From the [documentation](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#working-with-chrome-extensions) I found:

- To use a puppeteer extension it must be headless: false
- Chrome extensions do not support content scripts

Do you have any suggestions on how to do it?
I have tried this I can see the extension button correctly showing in the navbar of puppeteer launched browser but the content scripts JS is not executed and nothing it's printing in the console.
Moreover, using headless: false creates problems on the server, how can I run the extension in headless: true mode?

Said in other words, how can I run an automated test of a Chrome extension that use content scripts?

```
options = {
headless: false, 
devtools: true,
args: [
 `--disable-extensions-except=../extension/`,
 `--load-extension=../extension/`
]
}
```

Comment: You will have to setup a headless display instead of a headless server. See this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51883055/running-puppeteer-with-xfvb-headless-false. This display needs to be setup on the remote server and not on your machine